# Flutter Object3D throws invalid double while parcing .obj(Object file)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I was exploring [Object3D](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_3d_obj) package  it worked fine for some .Obj files but fails on some files with no errors and on some, it throws this error message

```
        The following FormatException was thrown during paint():
    Invalid double
    
    The relevant error-causing widget was:
    CustomPaint file:///C:/Users/Tiwari/.AndroidStudio4.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_3d_obj-0.0.6/lib/flutter_3d_obj.dart:120:18
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    #0      double.parse (dart:core-patch/double_patch.dart:111:28)
    #1      _ObjectPainter._parseObjString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_3d_obj/flutter_3d_obj.dart:190:37)
    #2      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:313:8)
    #3      _ObjectPainter._parseObjString (package:flutter_3d_obj/flutter_3d_obj.dart:177:11)
    #4      _ObjectPainter.paint (package:flutter_3d_obj/flutter_3d_obj.dart:316:22)
    ...
    The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomPaint#b558d relayoutBoundary=up4
    ...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
    ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=423.5, 0.0<=h<=799.2)
    ...  size: Size(40.0, 40.0)
    RenderObject: RenderCustomPaint#b558d relayoutBoundary=up4
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=423.5, 0.0<=h<=799.2)
    size: Size(40.0, 40.0)
```

File Downloaded from [here](https://free3d.com/3d-model/lowpoly-laptop-with-textures-255359.html)

**How should I debug this**, this error comes from package but does not gives the values at which it failed, I tried to use the debugger and also tried to print values by editing the package files but didn't work.